# Why is Mocha returning undefined when testing function that uses a promise?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am having an issue  with Mocha returning an incorrect result when testing a function that uses a promise.  Not sure why it is returning "undefined" - the function being called (testFunction()) shouldn't be returning until the promise is completed.

**Test:**

```
it('test1', function() {

    let testResult = testFunction();

     assert.equal(testResult,'success');


 });
```

**Promise:**

```
getPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
          resolve('success');
      }
}
```

**testFunction()**

```
testFunction = () => {

               getPromise().then(result => { return result}
      ).catch(error =>{  return error });

         }
```

**Result:**
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: undefined == 'success'

Comment: `result => return result` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Fixed the syntax in the post, but already had it correct in my test - that isn't the issue.

Comment: well the issue is that `testFunction` doesn't return anything, so it returns `undefined` by default. That is obviously not the same as `"success"`.

Comment: How does it not return anything?  It has return statements within the promise callbacks.

Comment: `within the promise callbacks` You need a return in testFunction as well. A return in the promise callback only specifies what code should run when the promise resolves.

Comment: I dont know much about mocha but I have experienced with Jest . For promise case , I do normally by `async await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testFunction` does not have a return statement in it, and so it is returning undefined. The returns in the callbacks only determine what the callbacks return, not what testFunction returns.

Since you're dealing with promises, you will have to return a promise. You can't return a string, because that string doesn't exist yet. So, testFunction might look like this:

```
testFunction = () => {
  return getPromise()
    .then(result => { return result })
    .catch(error => { return error });
}
```

But this `.then` is not doing anything, so unless there's some extra code you didn't mention, it can be removed:

```
testFunction = () => {
  return getPromise()
    .catch(error => { return error; });
}
```

Your test will need to be written to expect a promise to be returned. This is easiest if you use an async function, as in:

```
it('test1', async function () {
  let testResult = await testFunction();
  asset.equal(testResult, 'success');
});
```

Alternatively, you can use a `done` callback to tell the test when your async work is finished.

```
it('test1', function (done) {
  let promise = testFunction();
  promise.then(testResult => {
    assert.equal(testResult, 'success');
    done();
  });
});
```